# Multi layer docker image , The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I am little new to docker images, building a multilayer docker image, to consider the image as Jenkins Agent to execute maven & docker builds.

**Multi layer docker file:**

```
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 as maven
COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/conf/ # customized settings.xml 
FROM docker:24.0.0-rc.1-dind as dockerdind 
RUN cd /root &&  mkdir .docker  
COPY --from=maven . /
```

With the above docker file, I am creating a image and creating a pod with the final image. Inside the pod, If i execute mvm commands, i am getting below error

```
 mvn -version
/usr/bin/mvn: line 97: which: command not found
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.
```

If i create a pod with only `maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17` image, i am able to execute mvn commands inside the pod/container.

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.8.3 (ff8e977a158738155dc465c6a97ffaf31982d739)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 17.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/java/openjdk-17
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
```

Comment: add this line, ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/openjdk-17 as per error this should work.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good practice to simply merge the maven+jdk filesystem into dind docker image. Better stick to one image and perform installation of the other, e.g start with maven+jdk and install dind, or start with dind and install maven+jdk